# Is it possible to make a website to broadcast package of data for a Bluetooth 5 Coded PHY device to receive it?

Tags: web-applications, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to make an web application to broadcast/advertise a small package of data(around 40 bytes of string) for a Bluetooth 5 Coded PHY to scan it and receive a data. How would I start out to do it? Is there any library with node.js, or flask to do it?

I have start researching but not really found any resource.

Comment: You need to focus your question to a specific programming problem.